# Rotate a png image in opengl using windows

Tags: opengl

We are using a semicircle as a png image and we are rotating to fit into the circle border we are using opengl rotate API we are not getting the proper solution,can any specify what is the reason.

```
glm::mat4 transform;
transform = glm::rotate(transform, glm::radians(-60.0f), glm::vec3(m_fAltXPos, m_fAltYPos, 0.0f));
GLuint transformLoc = glGetUniformLocation(m_uiProgram, "transform");
glUniformMatrix4fv(transformLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(transform));
    if (m_ucType == VTD_INTRUDER_RA)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_uiTextures[VTD_INT_TEX_ORA]);
    else
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_uiTextures[VTD_INT_TEX_OTA]);

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

where m_uiTextures is used for loading texture.

Comment: "we are not getting the proper solution" - you may want to be a bit more specific about what exactly you expect vs. what you get (screen shots might help).

Answer (score 1):

From my guessing , you are drawing a quad on a 2d surface with no "to world coordinates" transformation , but you still rotate in 3d and its not good.

glm::rotate expects you to provide a matrix to store the rotation , a rotation angle and around which axis to rotate.
if you want to rotate around the x axis:

```
transform = glm::rotate(transform,angle,glm::vec3(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
```

or maybe you want to rotate around y and z axis

```
transform = glm::rotate(transform,angle,glm::vec3(0.0f,1.0f,1.0f)'
```

Change

```
transform = glm::rotate(transform, glm::radians(-60.0f), glm::vec3(m_fAltXPos, m_fAltYPos, 0.0f));
```

to

```
transform = glm::rotate(transform, glm::radians(-60.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
```

just because you work in 2D space and you won't benefit from rotations around x or y axis.